# Two different ways of defining ordered field?

Tags: analysis, field-theory

An ordered field is a field with total ordering **such that**,

- if $a\le b$ then $a+c\le b+c,$
- if $0\le a$ and $0\le b$ then $0\le ab.$

However, it seems there's another way to put **the "such that" part** as follows:

- ...
- if $a\le b$ and $0\le c,$ then $ac\le bc.$

Are these two equivalent...? If so, can you give me some hints why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that the latter set implies the former.

So suppose the relation satisfies the first set of conditions and let's prove that $a\le b$ and $0\le c$ implies $ac\le bc$.

First, prove that $a\le b$ is equivalent to $0\le b-a$ (by applying the property relative to addition). Then we have
$$
0\le (b-a)c
$$
Now $(b-a)c=bc-ac$ by the field properties, so $0\le bc-ac$ and therefore $ac\le bc$.